# Why companies have own DNS?

Tags: networking

Why do companies have their own DNS rather than public (google)? Can you please give me some ideas? It would be much appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow! [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Very quick answer:**

DNS is used basically to control on which websites are accessible by the employees.
ISP has basically the same feature.

Of course, that's just for common people since it doesn't block any IP address, websites might still be accessible from their IP.

It's as similar as removing entries in a search engine at an upper layer. Websites are still accessible with their domain but aren't easy to find.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, Alexis. So, it helps in maintaining the security of the company by providing access to specific websites.

Comment: It can be a security but I'd say mainly for disabling videos streaming services or life stories websites etc... It can be used also in schools. But there are also many other ways to do so.

Comment: Thanks, Alexis, it was really helpful.